# Why I am not allowed to delete more than 5 answers in a day

Tags: feature-request, answers, rate-limiting, self-delete

I want to cleanup my answer due to whatever reasons.

I get an error something like `I have already deleted 5 post......`

Why is this restriction.

Comment: To prevent rage quitters from deleted all their posts

Comment: No, you simply can't. Why would you do that anyway?

Comment: BTW are you requesting to remove this restriction?

Comment: Do you want to delete all your [545 Answers](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1668533/satpal?tab=answers) at SO?

Comment: Do they make the Internet better? Don't delete. Do they make it worse? Delete. More or less? Leave it alone, eventually you'll get upvotes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This restriction is in place to prevent users who want to quit Stack Overflow and delete all their content from doing so.

It happened before that a user gets frustrated and wants to quit Stack Overflow. Deleting valuable content should be stopped.

You can only delete 5 posts every day. There is no expansion to that.

Comment: Note that If you want to quit, you can ask that your posts are disaccociated with your account. This will keep the content.